# how do I mix two types in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have a div which contains both `<p>`'s and `<ul>`'s.
They have no classes or ids, so I need to iterate them all and activate some logic according to the content.

If I had only `<p>`'s it was easy:

```
    entry_content = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "entry-content")]')

    all_p = entry_content.xpath(('.//p//text()')).extract()

    for p in all_p:
        #do some logic according to content
```

The thing is that in those `<p>`'s hides a `<ul>` (one or more) with `<li>`'s in it.

How can I make a "united list" of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of:

```
entry_content.xpath('.//p//text()')
```

You can use a XPath like:

```
entry_content.xpath('.//*[name()="p" or name()="ul"]//text()')
```

#### Read more:

- [Nice XPath tutorial](http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html)
- [name() function in XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name)

Comment: thanks! You have redundant parenthesis in your answer :)